# How to identify number of single section for printing in MS Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

The input box "pages" in the print menu accepts the input "s17" for printing the 17th section of a document. But how do I find the correct number of the section (without counting manually from begin of document)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-click in the header area or select it from "Insert ribbon\Header\Edit Header."
The little tooltip below the header shows the section # that you're looking at.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to customize the status bar (the bar at the bottom of the screen that displays the current page and other information). Right-click on it and check "Section". The status bar will now display the current section at all times.

Comment: That's it. I have many sections on one page, and the Header does not show me what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I have set the status bar to display the section and page numbers, but find that in some documents neither the page nor section info updates (e.g., no matter what page I'm on it reads PAGE:1 Section:1).

So "double-clicking in the header to identify the section number" is really welcome knowledge.  Thank you to Wally for providing this information.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1107621)